# Why isn't my RL model behaving the same after being loaded in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm training some simple neural networks for Reinforcement Learning in Pytorch. At the end of the training, I save the model like so:

```
torch.save(self.policy_NN.state_dict(), self.model_fname)
```

It's doing pretty good at this point. Then later, in another script, I load it again, like so:

```
self.policy_NN.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_fname))
```

And then just play out the episode, as if the training never stopped (except I'm not doing DQN learning anymore, it's just taking the greedy action at each point). So I'd expect it to behave basically as it did when I saved it.

However, whenever I load it, it behaves completely differently, to the point that it seems like it didn't learn at all before I saved it. For example, if I look at the last 1000 time steps of the training session, it will get many rewards, but after loading it, it gets basically none.

I've verified (by doing `print(self.policy_NN.state_dict())`) that the weights and biases are in fact the same when I save the model and when I load it again.

What could be going on? Is there something else to the network that might not be getting saved somehow?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you figure it out by any chance? Even I don't use any dropout and my function approximator is a simple MLP.

Answer (score 0):

Dropout and some other layers behave differently in `eval` and `train` mode. You can switch between these by `model.train()` and `model.eval()`.

I remember reading that RL typically suffers from brittle learning where changing the input even slightly causes wildly different performance. The example was when training an algorithm on an Atari game and simply by shifting the screen right by one pixel the network lost all performance gains.

You might want to check that in both modes your environment behaves similarly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm not using any dropout, it's a pretty simple NN with 1 hidden layer, so there are really only two sets of weights and biases. I tried doing model.eval() after loading the state dict, but no luck. To your second point, it's really weird, because my environment is basically exactly the same in the two instances.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in inference, you don't use randomness for a specific times of runs before using the knowledge of your trained model. You should directly use the knowledge of the trained model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).